# Godot model import has strange corrupted textures for GLTF model

Tags: godot, godot4

In Godot 4, I am trying to import a model of a pinata that I created for a game. I created a UV map for this model, and have exported with the default settings, and yet it seems that the UV map is corrupted on the mesh.

Upon dragging in the model I created in blender, I get the following:

Broken model:
[image]

What the model is supposed to look like:
[image]

What the uv map is meant to look like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soR0g.png

What the uv map is coming up as in godot:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjEyX.png

I tried to add the UV map as a material, but I couldn't figure out how to add it correctly. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This was stupid of me, but I solved it by changing the image compression in the import tab up the top left next to the scene tab from Vram compressed to lossless.